# Using LEDs in an output of a power supply with a voltage divider

Tags: power-supply, led, voltage-divider

First time posting here; it is also my first time making a power supply as a group project (been in charge for the schematic). I've already learned about transformers, rectifiers, filters, and regulators (basic stuff). However, I'm having problem with loads connected after the regulator. Like a typical power supply, I'd like my output voltage to be specific (0V, 3V, 4.5V, 6V, 9V, and 12V in my case). I was able to emulate this by using a rotary switch and a bunch of resistors as voltage dividers. However, I'd like to add components where each voltage output will have a specific LED as an indication which output voltage is being drawn from the output terminals.

Here is my circuit for the whole power supply:
[image: Power supply]

So basically, I'd like to add an LED for each switch. How do I go about this? I can't just put it adjacent to the switch since it'll result to a different voltage reading from the voltmeter, right? Should I just use a bunch of Zener diodes in different voltages instead of using a voltage divider. Also, how can I maintain a constant brightness of the LED considering each output voltage is different.

Comment: This linear method is very inefficient . Reconsider scrapping this design, using variable ratio feedback to adjust output of a Buck regulator.. Current sensing is the answer to regulating LED power for different string sizes. Thus CC LED drivers are common commercial cheap solutions over a wide range of voltages. Also PWM methods with filtering and current sensing are used. Shop and learn.

Comment: You cannot use a resistor voltage divider that way to set output voltages of your supply.  The voltage at an output will depend greatly on the current drawn from that output, as the output current will pass through the upper resistors, changing the voltage drop across them.

Comment: This circuit is more of a voltage reference than a power supply. Even the 12V level won't be 12V if you draw much current from the output. The other levels will vary with ANY load current. What kind of loads are you expecting.. can you use transistors at all?

Comment: We can't use transistors unfortunately. Yeah, that's another problem but can I just reduce the resistor value in the voltage divider to compensate for the said low current?

Comment: Not unless you want to adjust it for every load condition....

Answer (score 1):

It's not much of a power supply- you won't be able to draw much power from the middle voltages without dropping the voltage significantly. It would be better to switch resistors on something like an LM317 (and make special accommodation for the 0V by shorting it directly to ground since you can't get below 1.25V with an LM317- a typical situation with regulators in general, though the reference voltage may vary).

You have an interesting problem in that you have expanded the scope of the project (adding LEDs) in a way that will be more difficult to accommodate than if you had considered it to begin with. It's not an unusual situation to occur in the real world.

One rather crude method would be to use the switches to operate telecom style DPDT relays and use one contact for the voltage selection (by whatever means) and use the other to activate the appropriate LED. You would need 6 relays and one resistor.

A better way might be to use a couple analog switch arrays such as [CD4066](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=schs051&fileType=pdf) quad switches, and control both the LED and the analog switch with the mechanical switch. The analog switch would select the desired voltage.

Comment: Unfortunately, we're limited to using Zener diodes. We can't use IC's. I also can't find rotary switches which are DPDT. Any other way to do it? I was thinking of using different Zener diodes instead. Since the 12 V is already DC, can I just place parallel diodes with different voltages and use that as the connection to my voltmeter?

Comment: @OrlandoLewis: If you are using a single rotary switch to select output voltages, you should be able to find a two pole, six position rotary switch.  One pole would select the output voltage, and the other would apply power to the appropriate LED.

Comment: Rotary switches are not called DPDT- it would be a 2 pole x position (x = 6) and they are VERY common. This would be your best bet. I suggest using a stack of zeners rather than the divider or your voltage regulation will be horrible.

Comment: Yeah, what @PeterBennett said.

Comment: I don't quite understand how will I be able to utilise the poles in the rotary switch. Does that mean I can retain my circuit as shown in the image?

Comment: Yes you can. Just use put a resistor to the unregulated supply from the common and connect an LED from each switch position to ground.

Comment: What do you mean by the unregulated supply exactly?

Comment: Wouldn't that still affect my output voltage?

Comment: The unregulated supply is the (unmarked as such) positive terminal of the 470uF electrolytic capacitor C1. No it won't affect the output voltage very much if your Zener is in regulation and one LED will always be on anyway.